# Como chamar um arquivo html para responder no express

Tags: html, node.js, express.js

Quero **chamar um arquivo HTML**, página já pronta, **para ser respondido pelo express**, mas apenas consigo escrevendo no .send()

**Da errado:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const site = require('./index.html');


var adminRes = express();

adminRes.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id; 
    res.send(site) //Da errado
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        text: "testando!"
    })
});

app.use('/admin', adminRes)
app.listen(4141, () => console.log('API correndo!'));
```

**Da certo:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const site = require('./index.html');


var adminRes = express();

adminRes.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id; 
    res.send(` <h1>oi!!</h1>`) //da certo
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        text: "testando!"
    })
});

app.use('/admin', adminRes)
app.listen(4141, () => console.log('API correndo!'));
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A palavra-chave require, deve ser utilizado para carregar módulos (arquivos com extensão `.mjs`) ou a partir da pasta `node_modules`. Também para carregar arquivos com extensão `.json` ou `.js`.

Desta forma para fazer funcionar o seu exemplo que "dá errado", o correto seria exportar uma função que retorna o seu html e criar um novo arquivo `index.js` que vai ser feito o `require` em seu módulo.

Em resumo temos:

- Criar um arquivo `xxx.js`
- exportar a função site do arquivo `xxx.js`
- fazer o require do arquivo `xxx.js` (o arquivo que foi criado no passo 1)

Crie o arquivo `xxx.js` com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
module.exports = function (){
    return `
    <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
      <title>oi</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <h1>oi!!</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
  `;
}
```

Repare que o conteúdo desta função deve ser o seu html. Isso é apenas um exemplo.

Depois alterar a maneira que você importa seu modulo `xxx.js` com o `require`, da seguinte forma:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const site = require('./xxx.js');


var adminRes = express();

adminRes.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id; 
    res.send(site()) //invocar a função, repare no parêntesis -->site()<--
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        text: "testando!"
    })
});

app.use('/admin', adminRes)
app.listen(4141, () => console.log('API correndo!'));
```

---

Se quer apenas servir o html estático, que nunca muda que não tem nenhum tipo interação com entrada de dados e processamento da requisição baseada em parâmetros, existem soluções específicas para esta necessidade e que já são implementadas pelo express.
Vou mostrar duas formas que podem ser utilizadas em seu módulo.

---

Utilizar a função [sendFile](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile), um exemplo deste uso é o seguinte:

você vai ter que importar o módulo [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) e adicionar o caminho absoluto do arquivo html que deseja servir.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path') //<--Importar o módulo path


var adminRes = express();

adminRes.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.id;
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html')) //<-- utilizar a função sendFile
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        text: "testando!"
    })
});

app.use('/admin', adminRes)
app.listen(4141, () => console.log('API correndo!'));
```

A função sendFile vai Transferir o arquivo no diretório fornecido. Definir o cabeçalho HTTP de resposta e o Content-Type com base na extensão do nome do arquivo.

Para mais informações consulte a [documentação](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile).

Comment: Obrigado, consegui ter uma base. Mas tenho uma pergunta: Por que chamar path, não apenas usar o sendfile(__dirname + "/index.html"), por exemplo?

Comment: pra este teu caso específico é indiferente, mas caso fosse necessário utilizar um diretório um ou mais níveis acima, não seria possível. Por exemplo, se for uma estrutura de diretório que inicie com `..`. Por ex.: `../views/index.html`. @Luka

Answer (score -1):

Você pode tentar usar a função `adminRes.use(express.static("nomeDaPastaDeArquivos")` para servir arquivos de uma certa pasta dd su aplicação.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

// Defina o caminho para a pasta com os arquivos que deseja servir
const pastaDosArquivos = path.join(__dirname, 'sua_pasta');

// Configure a rota para servir os arquivos estáticos
app.use(express.static(pastaDosArquivos));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Bem-vindo! Para acessar os arquivos, vá para /nome_do_arquivo');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Servidor rodando em http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Você deve conseguir acessar os arquivos dessa pasta usando uma URL no navegador como a seguinte `http://localhost:3000/arquivoName.html`. Caso queira mudar essaa URL a ser usada tente `app.use('/arquivos', express.static(pastaDosArquivos));`  desta forma os arquivos devem esta disponíveis através da URl `http://localhost:3000/arquivos/arquivoNamr.html`